# Two problems on the convergence of a sequence: $a_n= \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$ and $a_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was asked to determine whether the following two sequences were convergent or divergent. I want to make sure my reasoning as well as my justifications were correct, since I am very new on the subject.

A) $a_n= \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$

B) $a_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$

A) I began observing that

$$a_n = \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot  (2n-1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot  (2n-1) \cdot 2n \cdot (2n+1)} = \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}= 0$$

We thus determine the sequence converges to $0$.

B) The first attempt was to examine whether the limit of the absolute value of the sequence was $0$, but since this was not the case I determined that

$$a_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n= \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}((-1)^{n+1})}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})} = \lim_{n\to\infty}((-1)^{n+1})$$

which diverges by virtue of its continuous oscillation between $1$ and $-1$.

I want to know not only if my answers are correct, but especially if they are correctly justified. Particularly, does it suffice to simply state that $\lim_{n\to\infty}((-1)^{n+1})$ diverges because it constantly goes from $1$ to $-1$? It seems "obvious" to me, but it seems rather formally improper to state "the limit doesn't exist because it 'obviously' oscillates".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (A) you did is good.

For (B), since the limit $(-1)^n$ doesn't exist, you can't use the notation $\lim (-1)^n$, instead you can consider two subsequences, $a_{2k}, a_{2k+1}$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}  a_{2k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{-1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}}=-1,~~~\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{2k+1}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}}=1$$

The two subsequences converge to different limits, therefore the limit doesn't exist for $a_n$

Comment: Oh, that way of proving the divergence of the second sequence is cool. I presume it is standard procedure to prove divergence via showing two  "sub-sequences" converge to different limits. I'll keep that in mind for future problems. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, to prove a sequence divergent, you can show two subsequences converging to two different limits. Glad it helps :)